# Zabbix: expand macros in the name of the trigger, when retrieving events

Tags: zabbix

I use `event.get` to retrieve events, and provide `selectRelatedObject` parameter to get what in my case is the corresponding triggers. The `description` for that trigger may contain macros, which arrive in non-expanded form. I haven't found any additional parameter I can provide to `event.get` to get these macros expanded.

Yes, I can call `trigger.get` with `expandDescription` on that particular trigger, but this will require sending additional request to Zabbix server.

So the question is: **is it possible to get events with macros expanded for the corresponding triggers, with a single request?** Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible currently. A closely related feature request is https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2768 - it is not completely clear whether it would result in a different value expansion support, or name expansion support for `event.get`.